# Angular 2 Error Http

Tags: angular

Good morning,
I am trying to read data from a database from an external page:

'http://bicicardpruebas.itcl.es/prodwservice/api/instalacion/1'

I have a service that has this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class Ganado2Service {

    private url: string = 'http://bicicardpruebas.itcl.es/prodwservice/api/instalacion'

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getCiudad(id: string): Observable<String> {
        let ciudad: String = null;
        return this.http.get(this.url + '/' + id)
            .map(response => {
                let dbCiudad: any = response.json();
                ciudad = dbCiudad.id;
                return ciudad;
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    handleError(error: any) {
       let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
        error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

And I have a component that has this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BaMenuService } from '../../theme';

import {Ganado2Service} from './ganado2/ganado2.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'ganado',
    templateUrl: './ganado.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./ganado.scss']
})
export class GanadoComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private ganadoService: Ganado2Service) { }

    ngOnInit() {
         this.ganadoService.getCiudad("1").subscribe(ciudad => console.log(ciudad));
    }

}
```

When I run it on the console I get the following error:

Failed to load http://bicicardpruebas.itcl.es/prodwservice/api/instalacion/1: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

What could be the problem?

Comment: try jsonp https://angular.io/api/http/Jsonp

Answer (score 0):

The requested url does not allow cross origin request. That means only pages from the same domain can make request to that url. Therefor your browser stops it. If you are using the cli you can use it to create a local proxy. 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md .